# SharePoint 2010: How hide the menu for Welcome control

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

How to hide the dropdown menu in the Sharepoint 2010 Welcome control, that looks like this:

```
 <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
```

for public user the dropdown menu should not be required?

Answer (score 1):

first you should add a loginview to the master page and add a style tag into the anonymous template.

then you can paste something like this

```
.ms-welcomeMenu{display:none}
```

I haven't tested yet but the style should be pretty close